# How to replace top fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an application with 4 fragments: MainFragment, ActionFragment, DoneFragment, FailedFragment. When application launched it shows MainFragment. Than application receive some event and show ActionFragment with two buttons 'yes' and 'no'. If user press 'yes', applicaiton shows DoneFragment, otherwise FailedFragment. When user press  one time to back button on ActionFragment, DoneFragment or FailedFragment application must show MainFragment.

Improtant: if ActionFragment, DoneFragment or FailedFragment already opened and some event is occure again, application should show ActionFragment fragment with new event data.

So, I need:

- if ActionFragment, DoneFragment or FailedFragment already opened and event occur, I should replace top fragment with ActionFragment
- Otherwise I should simply add ActionFragment.

I am trying:

```
fun addOrReplaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val previous = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if (previous == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE)
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)
    } else {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(previous.id, 0)
        fragmentTransaction.remove(previous)
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
// ...
addOrReplaceFragment(ActionFragment(), "singleTag")
// ...
addOrReplaceFragment(DoneFragment(), "singleTag")
// ...
addOrReplaceFragment(FailedFragment(), "singleTag")
```

Here is popBackStack() doesn't work. When ActionFragment is opened, DoneFragment or FailedFragment just adding above. And user have to press back two times to get back to MainFragment.

I am find solution change popBackStack() to popBackStackImmediate(). It works well, but if activity is minimized it produce crash with IllegalStateException, because popBackStackImmediate() cannot be called after onSaveInstanceState().

How to replace top fragment and avoid IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.FragmentToBeReplaced,theFragmentToBeAdded);
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#isStateSaved()

Use `isStateSaved` to avoid losing state when a transaction happened.

And I think [Android navigation component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) might be easier way to navigate between fragments.

Comment: Do you mean `if (!isStateSaved()) { addOrReplaceFragment(ActionFragment(), "singleTag") }`? But in this case fragment will not changed when application is minimized.

Comment: Did you mean you need to execute transaction after `onStop`?

Comment: Yes. `commitAllowingStateLoss()` works well after `onStop()`.